# Valgrind not returning program's return value using lackey

Tags: valgrind

So say I have a very simple C program like this:

```
int main(){
    return 1;
}
```

I compile it into a.out. If I run

```
valgrind ./a.out
```

I can get a return value of 1. But if I run

```
valgrind --tool=lackey ./a.out
```

I get a return value of 0. So my question is, how can I get the return value of the program while using valgrind with lackey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lackey outputs a (confusing/useless) 'valgrind exit code' which is
as far as I can see in the valgrind source always equal to 0.
Of all the valgrind tools, only lackey is using this useless code.

However, the 'real' exit status (i.e. seen by the shell) is by
default the exit status of your program:

```
$ valgrind --tool=lackey a.out
...
==7033== Exit code:       0
$ echo $?
1
```

For tools that are reporting errors (e.g. memcheck), you can change
the exit code of the program if the tool detected an error, using the
option:

```
--error-exitcode=<number> exit code to return if errors found [0=disable]
```

Comment: Actually the thing is the exit status I get is still zero. If I do `valgrind --tool=lackey ./a.out` then `echo $?`, I won't get 1 but zero instead.

Comment: So, there is a bug in your environment. Double check the behaviour using " strace -f -o e.out valgrind --tool=lackey a.out". Valgrind will trace the client syscalls, strace will trace the resulting syscalls done by valgrind. In my case, I see that the client syscall is done : "SYSCALL[2098,1](252) exit_group( 1 ) --> [pre-success] Success(0x0)" and then in the strace outfile, I see that valgrind properly calls exit: "2098  exit_group(1)                     = ?" and "2096  exit_group(1)".  If you do not observe the same, file a bug on valgrind with all the details (platform, version, ...)

Comment: I did not see client syscall in Valgrind output.  Strace outfile has `13011 exit_group(0)                     = ?` . `13012 exit_group(0)                     = ?` . `13013 exit_group(1)                     = ?`

Comment: Looks like it is a bug on a old valgrind release(3.6.0). After upgrade it to 3.10.0, it is working as expected. Thanks @phd for the help.